# Breaking a video into frames with python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, wxpython, video-processing, audio-processing

I am trying to write a program that deletes frames of a video that don't have a particular symbol in them. My general plan:

1. Split the audio from the video
2. Split the video into frames
3. Run the frames through a subroutine that looks for the symbol, by checking the pixels where it should be for being the correct color, and logging the ones that don't.
4. Delete those frames and corresponding audio seconds
5. Splices it all back together.

I need some help finding libraries that can do this. I was wondering if `wxpython` could do the detection of pixel color. I have no idea what library could split audio and video and which could edit audio. I know ffmpeg could split the video into frames but after two days of work I still have not been able to install it for python 2.7, so I either need a way to install it or a different library to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: I would use a system call of `ffmpeg` for most steps except #3. For that I would use a combination of the libraries `PIL` and `scipy.ndimage`.

Comment: Are you aware of OpenCV project? As far as I understand it's capable of much more than just checking pixel color (which may be a too simplistic approach) - http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html

Comment: In fact, OpenCV has methods to read video files frame by frame, process those frames and write them back to another video file: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#capturefromfile - I found nothing about audio though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wxPython is mainly for desktop GUI development. I would look at pyAudio for the audio bit or possibly one of the following:

- http://xoomer.virgilio.it/sam_psy/psych/sound_proc/sound_proc_python.html
- https://github.com/Rudd-O/python-audioprocessing/
- http://code.google.com/p/pyo/

You might be able to use one of the Mplayer wrappers for the video:

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MplayerCtrl/
- http://code.google.com/p/python-mplayer/

Or check out that OpenCV project that Sergey mentioned:

- http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html