# Convert video into individual frames using Python without ffmpeg?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I need to compare 2 videos to check whether they are the same.

So I am planning to do the following:

1. Split both the videos into individual frames
2. Compare each frame with the corresponding frame of the ref video using `Python Image Lib`
3. Count the number of different frames to decide whether they are same.

I would like to know whether there is any function in Python to help me with the first step, i.e., to split the video into individual frames. I do not want to use `ffmpeg` to do the splitting.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Possibly covered here?:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729081/breaking-a-video-into-frames-with-python

Comment: Could not find the answer there since the option was to use ffmpeg

Answer (score 2):

You can use opencv

```
import cv2
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.94:554/stream3")


while True:
    # get frame by frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    cv2.imwrite('pic.png',frame)
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
```

Comment: I have tests where the streams would be long enough (like 4 hours or above). Will this method be apt in that scenario? Or is there a better option?

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking a simple question.. But I'm a newbie to python and OpenCV. But what does the following line do?
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.94:554/stream3")

Comment: This does not work. If I change it to save for every loop, it just makes thousands of blank images.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
currentFrame = 0
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Saves image of the current frame in jpg file
    name = './data/frame' + str(currentFrame) + '.jpg'
    print ('Creating...' + name)
    cv2.imwrite(name, frame)

    # To stop duplicate images
    currentFrame += 1

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#you can use this method
```